# Read access violation when compiling c++ code

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to use pointer in reading string array,but it occurs an exception.
Here is the code:

```
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int countn = 1;
class Solution {
public:
    string findPrefix(string compa, string& compb,int n) {
        string prefixi;
        for (int i = 0; i < compa.length(); i++) {
            if (compa[i] == compb[i]) {//Exception occurs here
                prefixi.push_back(compa[i]);
            }
            else break;
        }
        countn++;
        string* nxt = &compb;
        nxt++;
        if (countn<=n) {
            prefixi = findPrefix(prefixi,*nxt,n);
        }
        return prefixi;
    }
    string longestCommonPrefix(vector<string>& strs) {
        int n = strs.size();
        string prefix;
        prefix = findPrefix(strs[0], strs[countn],n);
        return prefix;
    }
};

int main() {
    vector<string> str = { "flower", "fly","flip"};
    Solution test;
    string ans = test.longestCommonPrefix(str);
    cout << ans << endl;
}
```

Exception occurs in line13

Then I checked the auto box and to find that the pointer nxt is pointing to the last string in str vector(string"filp"), I wonder if the pointer is out of boundary, but I do not know how to fix it and make my code work. Help me plz.

Comment: @drescherjm It's not immediately wrong in and of itself. `std::vector` provides contiguous storage, so this does get to the next string in the vector. Convoluted, yes, but not invalid. The problem is an off-by-one error: the code recurses once too many times and ends up looking past the end of the vector. I suspect that simply changing `if (countn<=n)` to `if (countn<n)` would make it work (exactly once, since it relies on a global variable).

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @Muhammad Mohsin Khan
I didn't know that since I'm new here. I' ve removed the image.

Comment: No problem. You can [edit] your question and write the error as text.